# Why isnt this input file clickable?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="mainSignup">
    <form id="signup">
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="username_enter">
            <label for="username">Username: </label> 
            <input type ="text" id="username" maxlength="10" placeholder="10 Characters Only">
        </div>
        <div id="password_enter">
            <label for="password">Password: </label> 
            <input type ="password" id="password" maxlength="50" placeholder="50 Characters Only">
        </div>          
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    label {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;


}

input {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#username_enter {
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -170px;

}

#password_enter {
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 53%;
  margin: -70px 0 0 -170px;

}

#username {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#password {
    margin-top: 160px;
}



#menu {
    border-radius:11px;
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
    border:6px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color:white;
}
```

Why isn't the username input not clickable?

Even when you clock on the word username it's not clickable as well.

Don't be amazed if this question is written badly because im only 11 yrs old.

aaaabbbbccccdddddeeeee

Comment: You're making Stack Overflow violate US law by having an account here. If you want to know why, you might like [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children%27s_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act)

Comment: ...For the record, I have nothing against you. I learning to code, and learning to love code, is the best thing kids can do. Unfortunately, US lawmakers decided that they'd make it incredibly dangerous for any company to store the information of anyone under 13 -- the penalties for violating COPPA are really serious -- so it's either go through a long, expensive process for everyone under 13, or sacrifice that segment of the population for, you know, paying all the other bills. It's a frustrating, stupid system, but that's the world we live in. That's why my first comment was harsh. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't interact with `username` input (cannot "click") because it is masked by `#password_enter` div element. Add the following line in CSS would quickly fix your problem:

```
#username_enter {
  ... your current css rules
  z-index: 99;
}
```

However, it's not a good idea to use so many `absolute` in such a simple example. Please consider using plain margin/padding to implement what you want.

Answer (score -1):

because label tags aren't clickable. you must use or `<button>` or `<a>`

Comment: But why is the password file clickable then?

Comment: Labels are clickable. On Chrome (probably others), if a `<label>` has the attribute `for` set to the ID of a valid form input, then clicking on the label will automatically move the focus to the associated input.

Comment: Yes they are clickable but they go to the input you linked to it.